# Why how do i this error when trying to free an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

***I would like to know how to free this array properly so I dont get this next error when i compile the file***. The "ooo" are the strings that i stored in the array

> ooo
> ooo
> ooo
> ooo
>
> Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:
> 0x0000000000400774
> Aborted (core dumped)

I am learning C, if someone can tell me how to fix the error and why it happened I would appreciate it thank you.

**here is the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define width 5
#define height 10

char** arrayFunction(){

    char** arrayInFunction = malloc(height * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0; i < height; i++){
        arrayInFunction[i] = malloc(width * sizeof(char));
    }
    return arrayInFunction;
    
}
int main()
{
    char** array = arrayFunction();
    array[0] = "ooo";
    array[1] = "ooo";
    array[2] = "ooo";
    array[3] = "ooo";

    for(int i=0; i < height; i++){
    printf("%s\n",array[i]);

    }
    
    //free the array created in main
    for(int i=0; i < height; i++){
    free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line: `replace `array[0] = "ooo";` sets the pointer that is in the memory location `array[0]` to point to the protected memory array that stores the value of the specified string.  You most likely can't free that memory.  What you want to do is to use the standard library function `strcpy` to copy the string `"ooo"` into the memory location that you previous allocated in the `arrayFunction` routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array[0] = "ooo";`

This changes the `char *` (a pointer to some `char`) in `array[0]` to point to the first character of `"ooo"`.  It now does no longer point to the memory you just allocated.

Thus when you attempt to free this memory, you're getting undefined behavior (= crash and error in your case).

You need to copy the contents of the C string `"ooo"` to the allocated memory, e.g. using [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) or (better) [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy).

---

Visualization; before:

```
array: [0][1][2][3][4]
        |
        v
       [?][?][?]... (the memory you allocated)
```

after:

```
array: [0][1][2][3][4]
      __|
     |  
     | [?][?][?]... (the memory you allocated, now lost; a memory leak)
     |
     v
   ['o']['o']['o']['\0'] (the C literal, wherever the C compiler saved it)
```

---

Other issues:

```
#define width 5
#define height 10
```

Better use `const` variables, or even better make these two parameters of the `arrayFuntion` (which should be named better!).

```
array[3] = "ooo";

for(int i=0; i < height; i++)
```

`array[4]` is left uninitialized. Accessing it (in the loop) is undefined behavior.

```
char** arrayInFunction = malloc(height * sizeof(char*));
```

Better avoid `sizeof(TYPE)` when you can, it's safer to use `sizeof(EXPRESSION)`, e.g. for above:

```
char** arrayInFunction = malloc(height * sizeof(*arrayInFunction));
```

Same for the other `sizeof` expression.

```
return 0;
```

Not necessary in `main`.